# Regular Expression, searching code in Dreamweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

I just need to search some code and find the following, using the find and replace with regular expressions in Dreamweaver:

```
<div id ="specific_div"> anything can be in here </div>
```

I have not really tried to tackle regular expressions yet, but I am having trouble figuring out how to tell it that "I don't care what is in between the div tags, but please find me this specific div tag, everything in it and the closing div tag!"

Answer (score 1):

There's a 'specific tag' option under the 'search' list in the 'Find and Replace' window. Why don't you use it? Anyway I'd probably use something like the following. But it won't select all the node if there's an idenatical closing tag `<div>` inside that div.

```
<div\b(.*?)(\bid)\s*=\s*("|')specific_div\3([\w\W]*?)</div>
```

I didn't close the opening tag because I thought you might have other attributes in that node. Oh and make sure the 'Match Case' option is not selected in the search window.

Comment: I have tried the specific tag option, and actually I just need to add two more closing div tags after the initial closing div tag but every time I use that with the specific tag function it won't add another tag. I will try again though and also explore your regex solution.